# how to pass a state as props which will update later with click event (and also keep the state updated at the same time)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**React**
i have tried to make a button which will show how many times it is clicked using react state. but i want to do this with many component. So i wrote my state and update function with setState in a parent Component and want to pass the state as props, but the problem is as i pass the state once, then after the state is updated (when the button is clicked)  the props dont update with that. and i cant see how many times the button is clicked.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 2,
    };
  }
  clickCount() {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      return { count: prev.count + 1 };
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainContent 
        handler={this.clickCount}  totalCount={this.state.count}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Which component are you trying to pass the state to? provide more informations???

Comment: I'm trying to pass the state to the "MainContent" child component

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have missed binding the function to **this**

```
class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               count: 2,
          };
          this.clickCount = this.clickCount.bind(this); // you may have missed this..
     }
clickCount() {
this.setState((prev) => {
  return { count: prev.count + 1 };
})
}
render() {
     return (
          <div>
               <MainContent handler={this.clickCount}  totalCount={this.state.count}/>
          </div>
      );
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: actually i am doing the eventlistener thing in the child component (MainContent). i'm using arrow function to use the "clickCount" function `onClick = { () => props.handler}`